# Can an audion tube amplify a pulsating direct current or must the current be converted first to an alternating current?

Tags: telephone, vacuum-tube

Can an audion tube use a pulsating direct current as input  and magnify the signal from the electrons flowing from the filament without first converting it to AC current? The reason I ask is that :

I am using diagrams form the 1940's and they are suggestive that the pulsating direct current is amplified as is. I find difficult since the amplification would only occur when the initial signal would increase in strength when the voice pressure waves were compressing the carbon in the transmitter but then on the weaker parts of the signal the polarity would be the same so it seems the voice would be distorted.

Now IF the pulsating direct current was FIRST converted to AC which I understand how to do and there are multiple ways to do this, and THEN that signal was fed into the audion tube , I understand since the audion tube would increase and decrease the strength of the signal as the grid changes polarity causing a uniform increase and decrease in strength.

Comment: Please add some schematics or the purpose of the device. I do not understand what are asking about.

Comment: No problem.  I'll do one better...you can see the tube and the flow at 8:08 minutes. "AT&T Archives: Bottle of Magic" . This appears on YouTube's AT&T Tech Channel.  It's easy , Just search YouTube for the title and simply use the scroll bar to fast forward till you get to 8:08 .

Comment: This is too confusing without a schematic.  What's a "audion" tube?  You seem to have some confusion between AC and DC.  The English is so bad as to be confusing.  Closing.

Comment: audion tube is a triode

Comment: A pulsating direct current is an AC current.

Comment: So if I hookup a microphone to a DC dry cell and speak into it , when the carbon granules compress and relax they produce a pulsating direct current.  You are saying that this pulsating direct current is also changing polarity as AC does ..which would mean it would change direction in my DC dry cell??

Comment: You are askng far too much if you expect people to watch videos just to understand what you're talking about. Your question must be complete here as asked.

Comment: I'm not asking you to watch anything ...it's a picture of the triode hookup a , a better drawing that I could make...but the point is mute the question has already been answered and I accepted the answer, thanx for reading but don't worry about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you are asking the principle about class A amplifier.  It doesn't matter if it is tube, transistor, ... The input signal is first coupled with a capacitor, which passes only AC signal. The the grid is biased with constant voltage and added the input AC signal. Lastly you need to decouple the output DC + AC signal with yet another capacitor.

Comment: Yes...that would certainly do it!...my question though is much more simpler than that!  Can a DC pulsating signal be amplified with out taking the intermediate conversion to and from AC as the video appears to suggest OR is the video incorrect ?

Answer (score 1):

The DC component will affect the grid bias, assuming you're talking about a common cathode amplifier.

How it will affect the grid bias I'm not going to speculate without seeing the schematic you're interested in. And no I'm not going to waste time searching for it.

But if the grid bias circuit is designed with this in mind, it certainly can work.